# Ace editor adding a red dot when clicking enter

Tags: ace-editor

This is the options i'm using for loading the editor

```
<div id="editor"></div>
<script>
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.setOptions({
            useWorker: false,
            highlightActiveLine: true,
            rtl: true,
            rtlText: true,
            enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
            enableSnippets: false,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: false,
            fontSize: "20px",
            showPrintMargin: false,
            showGutter: false,

        })
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    </script>
```

When I click "enter" a red dot appears, this is the element:

```
<span class="ace_invisible ace_invisible_space ace_invalid">·</span>
```

I don't want a live syntax checking, so I disabled the worker: `useWorker: false`
What else am I missing in the config to make it stop ?

After switching to the `src/` files, i've edited manually the `ace.js` file and saw that this code creates it:

```
 else if (controlCharacter) {
     console.log(`controlCharacter: (${controlCharacter})`);
     var span = this.dom.createElement("span");
     span.className = "ace_invisible ace_invisible_space ace_invalid";
     span.textContent = lang.stringRepeat(self.SPACE_CHAR, controlCharacter.length);
     valueFragment.appendChild(span);
}
```

As you can see I tried to log to console the problematic char - but it's giving a strange result:

```
console.log(`controlCharacter: (${controlCharacter})`);

# Gives in the Console tab in Firefox:
controlCharacter: (‫)
```

So I printed its code instead:

```
console.log(`controlCharacter: (${controlCharacter.charCodeAt(0)})`);

# Output
controlCharacter: (8235)
```

Which according to the web this is a right-to-left thing ( which I am using )

```
Unicode Decimal Code &#8235;
‫
Symbol Name:    Right-To-Left Embedding
Html Entity:    
Hex Code:   &#x202b;
Decimal Code:   &#8235;
Unicode Group:  General Punctuation
```

I'm loading:

```
    <script src="/js/ace-builds/src/ext-rtl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

How can I solve this ?

[image]

Comment: Created also: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/5423 as it seems when removing `rtlText: true` it doesn't occur, but then the blinking placeholder starts from the left vs the right ... sounds like a bug or something

Comment: They answered: This appears to be a regression introduced between versions 
blinking placeholder being shown on line start with rtl also seems to be a bug.